# Subtracting an integer from a value which is fetched using $(#id).val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In order to subtract an integer from a value which is fetched using `$(#id).val()` I have tried:

```
$("#hid_count").val() = $("#hid_count").val() - 1;
```

and:

```
count = $("#hid_count").val();
```

Here `hid_count` is a hidden field on the page. However, both of these are not working. An error is coming on the page. Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: you need to convert $("#hid_count").val() to int ....

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer don't bother, we've got 6 answers already :p

Comment: @NiftyDude actually, i also answered. I just withdrew it in favor of better ones.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer your answer was some latin essay :p

Comment: @NiftyDude if you edit it in less than 5 mins after first post, the history won't show.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yeah I know, was just messing around with you :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#hid_count").val(parseInt($("#hid_count").val(), 10) - 1);
```

Since you are reading a string, you have to make a `parseInt` before arithmetic operation

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds this time :)

Comment: When subtracting string are converted into integers automatically.

Comment: but this can lead to sneaky errors: he may have different arithmetic operation so I wouldn't rely on his specific example

Comment: @newprogress you can thank him by accepting his answer by clicking the little gray `V` sign below the number `3`

Comment: @F. Calderan  now how can I assign the calculated value back to hid_count?

Comment: this statement altready makes the subtraction and assigns the result to hid_count

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `parseInt()` to convert the `val()` from a string to an int, so that the arithmetic operation works correctly.

```
$("#hid_count").val(parseInt($("#hid_count").val(),10) - 1);
```

Comment: When subtracting string are converted into integers automatically.

Comment: It's still best practice IMO, if only for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#hid_count").val($("#hid_count").val() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**working demo click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scmsc/5/)

`parseInt`

http://www.minihowtos.net/jquery-parseint

**code**

```
alert(" ===> " + (parseInt($("#hid_count").val()) - 1));​
```

Comment: should probably include the relevant script here instead of just posting a link :)

Comment: Sorry bruvnor @NiftyDude was on my way to get my drink adding it now :P